# Selective Display of JSON data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have API which is sending me JSON data in react. It is basically sending menus to be shown to specific role.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
{
Menu : Home
Profile : End User
}
{
Menu : Add Questions
Profile : End User
}
{
Menu : Modify Answers
Profile : End User
}
------------------------------------------------- and another user JSON
{
Menu : Home
Profile : Admin
}
{
Menu : Approve Questions
Profile : Admin
}
{
Menu : Approve Answers
Profile : Admin
}
```

I have to show left hand side menu in react as below

**Welcome {User}, logged in as {Profile}**

- Home
- Add Questions
- Modify Answers

My Code is:

```
-----------------
return (
      <div class="content-section implementation button-demo">
        <h1>NK{userMenuResponse.Profile}</h1> //Not working
        {userMenuResponse.length
          ? userMenuResponse
               .map((menu, id) => (
                <div key={id}>

                  {menu.Menu} for {menu.Menu}

                </div>
              ))
          : null}
      </div>
    );
-----------------------------
```

With map function, I am getting profile repeatedly..Please guide. TIA

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt. Include any details about what is or isn't working, and what your expected result should be.

Comment: sorry for that, have added code. It is giving both menu and profile. However I want only Profile at the top while menu list down there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:** `userMenuResponse` is an array then `userMenuResponse.Profile` will OFC have an error, you need to access an object by index first, i.e. `userMenuResponse[0].Profile`

**Solution:** If you move the ternary outside the content then you can guarantee accessing `userMenuResponse[0]` will be defined. Then you can map the menus as usual. The `Fragment` is used to return a single node as per react convention.

```
return (
  <div class="content-section implementation button-demo">
    {userMenuResponse.length ? (
      <Fragment>
        <h1>NK{userMenuResponse[0].Profile}</h1>
        {userMenuResponse.map((menu, id) => (
          <div key={id}>
            {menu.Menu} for {menu.Menu}
          </div>
        ))}
      </Fragment>
    ) : null}
  </div>
);
```

***Suggestion*** for JSON data

```
[{
  Menu: "Home"
  Profile: "End User"
},
{
  Menu: "Add Questions"
  Profile: "End User"
},
{
  Menu: "Modify Answers"
  Profile: "End User"
}]
```

Preprocess it to reduce/normalize your stored/saved JSON data, it may be easier to consume if it had this shape

```
{
  profile: string,
  menus: string[]
}
```

I.E.

```
{
  profile: "End User",
  menus: [
    "Home",
    "Add Questions",
    "Modify Answers"
  ]
}
```

```js
const endUserData = [{
    Menu: "Home",
    Profile: "End User"
  },
  {
    Menu: "Add Questions",
    Profile: "End User"
  },
  {
    Menu: "Modify Answers",
    Profile: "End User"
  }
];

const adminData = [{
    Menu: "Home",
    Profile: "Admin"
  },
  {
    Menu: "Approve Questions",
    Profile: "Admin"
  },
  {
    Menu: "Approve Answers",
    Profile: "Admin"
  }
];


const normalizeData = data => data.reduce((data, item) => {
  if (!data.profile) {
    data.profile = item.Profile;
  }
  data.menus.push(item.Menu);
  return data;
}, {
  profile: '',
  menus: []
});

console.log(normalizeData([]));
console.log(normalizeData(endUserData));
console.log(normalizeData(adminData));
```

Then the render function can be simplified a bit to

```
return (
  <div class="content-section implementation button-demo">
    <h1>NK{data.profile}</h1>
    {data.menus.map((menu, id) => (
      <div key={id}>
        {menu.Menu} for {menu.Menu}
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```